# How can I save hexa number into a variable in lua?

Tags: lua, numbers, hex

How can I save hexa number into a variable in lua (as number and not as string) ?
I tried that:

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> vendor_rand=259754994c07a716565e459a64f2a8672c1956151249d8eaeb3f7f1c6513e0e1
stdin:1: malformed number near '259754994c07a716565e459a64f2a8672c1956151249d8eaeb3f7f1c6513e0e1'
```

but I got here an error.
I saw this option `tonumber("fe",16)` but it save it as a string and not as a number type.

Comment: use a string. there is no number type that can store a value that big. that would be 32 bytes...

Comment: Lua 5.1 is old as of now. Unless you are required to use it, better upgrade to Lua 5.4.4

Answer (score 2):

```
local hex = "259754994c07a716565e459a64f2a8672c1956151249d8eaeb3f7f1c6513e0e1"
```

There is no numeric type that could hold 32 bytes. Also there is no mathematical operation you could do with it that would make any sense.
So just use a string to store that number.

Comment: You are correct that this string is too long to fit in a number. Lua 5.1 doubles can accurately represent integers up to `2^53 - 1` though, and Lua 5.3+ integers can even represent integers up to `2^63 - 1`. It is probably possible to compile Lua with smaller numeric types like 32 bit ints or 32 bit floats.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because `259754994c07...` is not syntactically valid code. You have to use the `0x` prefix to write a number in hex format:

```lua
vendor_rand = 0x259754994c07a716565e459a64f2a8672c1956151249d8eaeb3f7f1c6513e0e1
```

However, this number is too big for Lua. On versions prior to 5.3, you will have a double precision loss (since Lua converts it to a double). On 5.3 onwards, you will have an integer overflow. For 32-bit systems, the maximum value an integer can hold is `2^31 - 1`, for 64-bit `2^63 - 1`.

At the time of writing this answer, Lua 5.1.5 is old. The latest version is 5.4.4 and is recommended to use unless you are required to use an older version.

**EDIT:** Thanks @[LMD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7185318/) for details.

Comment: Lua 5.1 doesn't have integers; you'll thus lose precision when Lua converts your number to a double (I get `1.7002953183934e+76`). On Lua 5.3+ you get an integer overflow; the largest positive number that Lua 5.3+ can represent is `2^63 - 1`.